# How to delete the space in between each column of the multiplication table?

Tags: java, loops, nested, format, nested-loops

I coded a multiplication table and I can't figure out how to delete the large amount of space in between columns. Here is my code:

```
public class Mult_Table
{
     public static void main (String []args)
     {
         int tablesize = 9;

         for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
         {
             for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
             {
                  System.out.print(i*j + "\t");
             }

             System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Output but there is more space in between columns:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  
3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  
4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  
5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  
6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  
7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  
8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  
9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81
```

Comment: `\t` will tab over to the next stop point, so I don't see a problem. How do you want it to look?

Comment: I did use \t but there is too much space in between each column. The output shown in the isn't the actual output that shows when I compile. There is more space that shows than on this post.

Comment: If you want a specific amount of space, you can just use spaces instead of `\t` and put however many you'd like, but be sure to account for two digit numbers, as they will need one less space than one digit to keep it aligned. I don't see anything wrong with using `\t`. Why do you need less space?

Comment: ok, When I output my code on my program, there is like 8 spaces in between each column. It is easier to read if it is closer together since it is a multiplication table. Thank you for your help also.

Comment: Ah, so for readability you want it closer. Understood.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Mult_Table
{

 public static void main (String []args)
  {
 int tablesize = 9;
   for (int i=1;i<=9;i++)
   {
    for (int j=1;j<=9;j++)
    {
        if((i*j)/10 > 0{
            System.out.print(i*j + " | ");
        }else{
            System.out.print(i*j + "  | ");
        }
    }
     System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

That should have one space and add an `|` between each number if you don't want that just delete it.

The only thing I've changed is I account for two digit numbers, `(i*j)/10`, this works because integer division will round "down", so until `i*j` is greater than or equal to `10`, it will be 0.

It should look similar to this

```
1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 
2  | 4  | 6  | 8  | 10 | 12 | 14 | 16 | 18 |
3  | 6  | 9  | 12 | 15 | 18 | 21 | 24 | 27 | 
4  | 8  | 12 | 16 | 20 | 24 | 28 | 32 | 36 | 
5  | 10 | 15 | 20 | 25 | 30 | 35 | 40 | 45 | 
6  | 12 | 18 | 24 | 30 | 36 | 42 | 48 | 54 | 
7  | 14 | 21 | 28 | 35 | 42 | 49 | 56 | 63 | 
8  | 16 | 24 | 32 | 40 | 48 | 56 | 64 | 72 | 
9  | 18 | 27 | 36 | 45 | 54 | 63 | 72 | 81 |
```